# Can't select Facebook SDK as a Library

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, sdk

I'm using phonegap/cordova on eclipse to build my app. I'm also trying to use the facebook sdk. I downloaded the android SDK and imported the facebook folder correctly. I'm receiving 300+ errors and I know it is because it is not linked. I right-clicked my main project -> Android -> but facebook is not being listed as an option.

How do I link Facebook SDK to my project?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use facebook js sdk and include it in your web app. Then whether you build your app for ios or android it will still work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Or

http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/18/pg-facebook-plugin/